# Can navigation occur after activity is destroyed

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I am running some asynchronous tasks.
After activity is destroyed, is it safe to navigate using the `INavigationService`?

It's not exactly clear to me what happens under the hood in both Prism and Xamarin Forms.

Here's an example:

```
await SomeAsyncTask();

// Suppose at this point, Activity was destroyed
// This means no UI. I'm not sure what's the state of Xamarin.Forms.Application at this point and everything else in Prism
_navigationService.NavigateAsync(...);
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information on what it is that you’re trying to do.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for reply. I added a code example. Does this help?